# Extract video or audio from frame index ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a list of frames index, for example: `[1,5,6,7,100,106,1100]`.

How I extract a video / audio from source video that only includes the above frames using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Using FFmpeg 's select filter. Note, frame numbers are zero-based.

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile.mkv -vf select='eq(n\,1)+eq(n\,5)+eq(n\,6)+eq(n\,7)+eq(n\,100)+eq(n\,106)+eq(n\,1100)' -vsync 0 -vframes 7 frames%d.jpg
```

Comment: That command is extract the image from video. I'd like to get the audio at the frames number too <audio from from frame number x to y..>.